# Legend for different curves on different places in gnuplot png terminal

Tags: png, gnuplot, legend

I want to place the titles of two curves on different places. For example for the first curve "set key top right" and for the second curve "set key bottom left" in PNG terminal. Tryind different combinations  I got nothing. Where is an error in the following file ? Thank you!

```
set key top right
plot sin(x)/x
unset key
set key bottom left
replot sin(x)
set term png 
set output "file.png"
replot
```

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot do this. One workaround is to use `multiplot` to stack the plots. But, if done properly, this requires you to use fixed margins, so that you may not have a very flexible solution:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'file.png'
set lmargin 5
set bmargin 2

set multiplot
plot sin(x)/x lt 1

unset tics
unset border

set key bottom left
plot sin(x) lt 2
unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: Damn it, you're fast... I was just writing the same thing... +1 Speedy

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a combination of set arrow and set label commands, e.g.,

```
set arrow 1 from 6,0.9 to 9,0.9 nohead lt 1
set label 1 'sin(x)/x' at 5.5,0.9 right
set arrow 2 from -4,-0.3 to -7,-0.9 nohead lt 2
set label 2 'sin(x)/x' at -7.5,-0.9 right
```